# Configure new site automatically

Tags: installation

Is there a way for me to automate the form-filling steps on a brand new site's `/install.php`?  I'm doing a bunch of experimenting where I set up a site inside a Docker container and try some stuff out, but filling out the installation forms dozens & dozens of times is getting pretty old.

My procedure for creating the Drupal site is:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:7.x-dev my-drupal --no-interaction
cd my-drupal/web
cp sites/default/default.settings.php sites/default/settings.php && chmod 666 sites/default/settings.php
chmod 777 sites/default
```

and then I go to the web interface & start entering stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drush [site:install](https://www.drush.org/12.x/commands/site_install/) does exactly this.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks, I had previously (years ago) tried this and couldn't get it working, I think my problem (judging by what happened just now) is that I was doing `--foo bar` instead of `--foo=bar` for everything.  Changing to that style made it work.